# How can I configure startup files so that I can show my disk usage every time I open a new bash?

Tags: bash, startup, du

I am having trouble finding out a way to configure Bash startup files so that it shows my disk usage every time I open a new Bash.

The script I am using is

```
s=$(du -sh --total | grep "total" | awk '{printf %.3f",$1/5000}')
echo "You are using $s% of your storage"
```

Comment: add it to you `.profile` file, each time you login it will display.

Comment: how do i do that? its probably a dumb question but i am pretty new in bash scripting

Comment: Note that you'll break fewer things if you have this write to stderr rather than stdout -- software like `rsync` that logs into your account over ssh doesn't expect (what is from its perspective) random garbage to be printed at login. Thus, you should probably tack a `>&2` onto the `echo`.

Comment: ...also note that in general, this kind of question is a better fit for one of our sister sites such as [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/); StackOverflow's scope is only about *software development*, not about system/prompt configuration/customization.

Comment: `du -sh --total | awk '/total/{printf "you are using %.3f of your storage\n", $1/5000}'`

Answer (score 1):

you can put it inside your .bash_profile

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

if you would like to add this for every user, then use /etc/bashrc file

```
vi /etc/bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Often the `~/.bash_profile` isn't run very often.  You should consider putting the command into the file `~/.bashrc` which typically is sources for each new interactive shell.

Read also the chapter `INVOCATION` in your shell's man page.